# How to rescale multiple attributes at the same time in R

Tags: r, attributes, dataset, scale, rescale

I have a data set that contains multiple attributes with integer values from 1 to 5 and I would like to rescale these attributes so that their values range from -1 to 1. My current code that I have is

```
    newdata$Rats = rescale(newdata$Rats, to = c(-1,1), from=c(1,5))
```

Where `newdata` is my dataset and `Rats` is one of my attributes. If I only had a few attributes to change that would be fine, but I have about 30 or so to change. Is there a way to use a for loop to do this or use the `select` function that R has or possibly another way?

Comment: Look at `?for` or `?lapply`, both would be helpful.

Comment: With `?apply` as: `DF = head(mtcars[,3:5]);apply(DF,2,function(x) rescale(x,to=c(-1,1),from=c(1,5)) )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lapply()`:

```
newdata[, c(1:30)] <- lapply(newdata[, c(1:30)], 
                             function(x) rescale(x, to = c(-1, 1), from = c(1, 5)))
```

For the `c(1:30)`, insert a vector of either positions of your variables within your dataframe, or a vector of the names of your variables as strings.